# html to pdf generation using itext in java

Tags: java, css, pdf-generation, itext

**Description**:
***ouput***: `pdf file`
***input*** : `index.css`, `bootstrap.min.css`, `index.html`

**Problem**: if i use index.css file without bootsrap its working fine, but when i use boot strap its throw exception.

**CODE is here:**

```
package test.test1;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.commons.codec.Charsets;

import com.google.common.io.CharStreams;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.Pipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.CssFile;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.StyleAttrCSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Tags;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.end.PdfWriterPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext;

public class Table {



    File oFile = new File("c:\\test\\1.pdf");
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter writer =null;

    public Table() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        oFile.createNewFile();
        writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(oFile));


        InputStream htmlpathtest = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("index.html");
        String htmlstring = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(htmlpathtest, Charsets.UTF_8));

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlstring.getBytes());

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

        writer.setInitialLeading(12.5f);

        document.open();

        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);

        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        // CSS
        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        InputStream csspathtest = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("css\\index.css");

        InputStream csspathtest1 = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("css\\bootstrap.min.css");

        CssFile cssfiletest = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(csspathtest);
        cssResolver.addCss(cssfiletest);
        cssResolver.addCss(XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(csspathtest1));


        Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,
                new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(
                        document, writer)));

        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.parse(is);
       document.close();
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {  new Table();}
}
```

**Exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "100%"    at
>   sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
>     at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:422)   at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.FontSizeTranslator.getFontSize(FontSizeTranslator.java:186)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.FontSizeTranslator.translateFontSize(FontSizeTranslator.java:165)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.startElement(AbstractTagProcessor.java:120)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.open(HtmlPipeline.java:105)
>     at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.startElement(XMLWorker.java:103)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.startElement(XMLParser.java:372)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.TagEncounteredState.process(TagEncounteredState.java:104)
>     at
>   com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:237)
>     at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:215)
>     at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:188)
>     at test.test1.Table.(Table.java:95)   at
>   test.test1.Table.main(Table.java:104)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK CSS support from the `itext` HTML renderer is very limited. I've recently used a more complete HTML to PDF library called [flying-saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) that supports CSS2 and some CSS3 features. `flying-saucer` uses `itext` as backend. You should give it a go - it might not support all bootstrap features but may be able to still fulfill your requirements.